# java read xml root node description using JAXP

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a simple xml document and I am trying to get the description of the root node using org.w3c.dom.Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><students   mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="students.xsd"><description>A bunch students and courses</description><student studentID="0144085" gender ="M"><firstname>Jack</firstname>
```

Here is my code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            builderFactory.setValidating(true);
            builderFactory.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE,
                    W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            // parse the input stream
            document = builder.parse(in);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // JAXP
            Node rootXMLNode = document.getDocumentElement();

            DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
            //jf : set StudentINfoSet class properties
            this.description = rootXMLNode.getTextContent();
                    //DOMUtilities.getAttributeString(rootXMLNode,"description");
```

Now the rootXMLNode.getTextContent(); returns the whole xml document as string, how can I just get the description tag of the root node then.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but the easiest would be using a method like `getElementsByTagName` to obtain the `description` element, then using `getTextContent`.

```
    Element rootXMLNode = document.getDocumentElement();

    //jf : set StudentINfoSet class properties
    this.description = rootXMLNode.getElementsByTagName( "description" )
            .item( 0 ).getTextContent();
```

However, it would probably be better to use something like XPath...